# web links are opened twice

Tags: bash, firefox, executable, url, default-browser

Since I installed **Firefox Quantum** and **Firefox ESR 52** both (**Kubuntu Trusty / KDE 4.13.3**) it happens every time that any external web link is opened twice in my default browser. So I presume this is an system issue and not a Firefox issue.

The only things I changed manually are that I added personal executable scripts in "**/usr/bin/**" and "**~/bin/**" and changed the default browser so that I don't mix up with both firefox installations.

So "**/usr/bin/**" contains "**firefox-esr**" and "**firefox.real**" (for Quantum) which both are simply links to the start files of the according program folders in "**/usr/lib/**". In addition it contains a script "**firefox**" which might be cause of my problem, but I cant see it.

Here is the "**/usr/bin/firefox**" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FIREFOX="$(which firefox)"
[ -x "$FIREFOX.real" ] && exec "$FIREFOX.real" "$@"
exec firefox-esr "$@"
```

→ **which** reports "~/bin/firefox" and "firefox.real" exists in both "/usr/bin/" and "~/bin/" directories as links to a script (*see below*).

Here is the "**/usr/bin/firefox.real**" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

MOZ_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/firefox
MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`which $0`
MOZ_APP_NAME=firefox

export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER

while [ ! -x $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME ] ; do
    if [ -L "$MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER" ] ; then
        MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`readlink -f $MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER`
        MOZ_LIBDIR=`dirname $MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER`
    else
        echo "Can't find $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME"
        exit 1
    fi
done

usage () {
    $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME -h | sed -e 's,/.*/,,'
    echo
    echo "      -g or --debug          Start within debugger"
    echo "      -d or --debugger       Specify debugger to start with (eg, gdb or valgrind)"
    echo "      -a or --debugger-args  Specify arguments for debugger"
}

moz_debug=0
moz_debugger_args=""
moz_debugger="gdb"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -h | --help )
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        -g | --debug )
            moz_debug=1
            shift
            ;;
        -d | --debugger)
            moz_debugger=$2;
            if [ "${moz_debugger}" != "" ]; then
          shift 2
            else
              echo "-d requires an argument"
              exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        -a | --debugger-args )
            moz_debugger_args=$2;
            if [ "${moz_debugger_args}" != "" ] ; then
                shift 2
            else
                echo "-a requires an argument"
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        -- ) # Stop option processing
            shift
            break
            ;;
        * )
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $moz_debug -eq 1 ] ; then
    case $moz_debugger in
        memcheck)
            debugger="valgrind"
            ;;
        *)
            debugger=$moz_debugger
            ;;
    esac

    debugger=`which $debugger`
    if [ ! -x $debugger ] ; then
        echo "Invalid debugger"
        exit 1
    fi

    case `basename $moz_debugger` in
        gdb)
            exec $debugger $moz_debugger_args --args $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
            ;;
        memcheck)
            echo "$MOZ_APP_NAME has not been compiled with valgrind support"
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            exec $debugger $moz_debugger_args $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
            ;;
    esac
else
    exec $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
fi
```

In addition to these I wanted to add my personal override executables under "**~/bin/**". Here I relinked "**firefox**" and "**firefox.real**" to "**./firefox-quantum**" which lets me run this with a separate profile – "**~/bin/firefox-quantum**":

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/firefox.real -no-remote -P "########.default-quantum"  "$@"
```

According to this I did the same with "**~/bin/firefox-esr**" which is my default browser (for the default profile):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/firefox-esr "$@"
```

The **default browser** command is now:

```
firefox-esr  -new-tab %u
```

Why are external web links opened twice?
I cannot find the problem.

Might the cause be the "**/usr/bin/firefox**" script? Shouldn't it start firefox twice because there is of cause "**firefox.real**" and so it should start "**firefox.real**" AND "**firefox-esr**"? Or didn't I understand the **exec** command?

Comment: I finally found the error myself: the additional `%u` parameter for the default browser was redundant.